# Python trouble with matching tuples

Tags: python, tuples

For reference this is my code:

```
list1 = [('10.180.13.101', '10.50.60.30', 'STCMGMTUNIX01')]
list2 = [('0.0.0.0', 'STCMGMTUNIX01')]

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        for k in j:
            print (k)
            if k.upper() in i:
                matching_app.add(j)


for i in matching_app:
    print (i)
```

When I run it, it does not match. This list can contain two or three variables and I need it to add it to the matching_app set if ANY value from list2 = ANY value from list1. It does not work unless the tuples are of equal length.

Any direction to how to resolve this logic error will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition for `matching_app`?

Comment: @crazyGamer it is just an arbitrary set that adds matching tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in a few different ways. Here are two approaches:

**Looping:**

```
list1 = [('10.180.13.101', '10.50.60.30', 'STCMGMTUNIX01')]
list2 = [('0.0.0.0', 'STCMGMTUNIX01')]
matches = []
for i in list1[0]:
    if i in list2[0]:
        matches.append(i)
print(matches)
#['STCMGMTUNIX01']
```

**List Comp with a `set`**

```
merged = list(list1[0] + list2[0])
matches2 = set([i for i in merged if merged.count(i) > 1])
print(matches2)
#{'STCMGMTUNIX01'}
```

Comment: But what is more interesting to know is why the original code doesn't work. Perhaps the comma was missing causing the strings to concat and give wrong result?

Comment: I think this works! I didn't think to check for the specfic position in the tuple because I can have the lists contain the same data type for the first position.

Comment: and if there is more than 1 tuple per list, you could flatten the tuples via comprehension

Comment: even with the comma, it still puts 0.0.0.0 in there as a match, when it is not a match @crazyGamer . I think the problem was just not unpacking the tuples nested inside the list

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear of what you want to do. You have two lists, each containing exactly one tuple. There also seems to be one missing comma in the first tuple.

For finding an item from a list in another list you can:

```
list1 = ['10.180.13.101', '10.50.60.30', 'STCMGMTUNIX01']
list2 = ['0.0.0.0', 'STCMGMTUNIX01']

for item in list2:
    if item.upper() in list1: # Check if item is in list
        print(item, 'found in', list1)
```

Works the same way with tuples.